# Going to a special month in a table with event using the current month as target

Tags: javascript, function, events, timeline, onload-event

I have a list of events during the year that it pretty long. It is a normal html-table. Now I want to avoid the user to have to scroll down the list to find the right month and the current events. (Switching to some kind of calendar is not on option for different reasons.) Having set an anchor (Month0 for January, Month1 for February etc.) before each month name, can I get the page to jump there on load through a script?

I haven’t written my own javascripts for some time now, but I imagine using bits like this

getMonth() 0-11

if getMonth(0)
onLoad go to "a href=#Month0"

Could this be made to work?

Answer (score 0):

For the parts you want to jump to, use an anchor like the code below.

```
<a name="Month0"></a>January
```

Then, to create a link that jumps there, you can do this.

```
<a href="#Month0">Jump to January</a>
```

You can also make a "Go to Top" button by not putting anything after the hashtag.

```
<a href="#">Go to the top of the page.</a>
```

This is especially useful when combined with CSS's position:fixed

```
<div style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:0px"><a href="#">Go to top</a></div>
```

That will cause the button to always stay on the bottom left.

If you want to accomplish this jumping effect in Javascript, you can use the location object, like so:

```
location.hash="#Month0";
```

And you could turn this into a function quite easily, too!

```
function getMonth(anchornum) {
location.hash="Month"+anchornum;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I have added id tags, but... the page is a trilingual one. This means the script would first have to detect with language to use, in order to jump to the right month.id. Either I use the same "month0" id tags in all language, or use "monat0" for the German and "månad0" for the Swedish one. But then I first need to determine the language. Thought about taking it from the referring page, but since there are other ways to get to the page, it is not a safe way. Putting the window.location in the URL won't work since I work with Wordpress. Or am I wrong there? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `<a>` tags next to the month names. You can set an id on any type of element and have it behave as a jump anchor.

If you set a link to an id it will jump the page to the element with that id. So:

```
<a href="#month0"></a>
```

will jump to the element with id month0, which in your case will likely be a table element:

```
<tr id="month0"></tr>
```

For your anchor points, you should us the id attribute rather than a name. The browser will look for your element by id first, and then by name if it doesn't find any element with the requested id.

Setting the window's location will also cause a jump to any element with a corresponding id.

```
window.location.hash = 'month0';
```

If the hash is already in the url when the page loads, you don't need any javascript to jump to the location. It will happen automatically.

Comment: I can't comment on someone else's post yet, so here's my response to your comment below: (1) you shouldn't be translating very many element attributes, and particularly not Ids or classes. That would make style sheet maintenance a nightmare. (2) unless you're using a comment widget or other wordpress plugin that attempts to set or retrieve the hash, you'll be fine using links with id hashes at the end. If you're not specifically altering your routing based on the hash, it will be ignored.

Comment: I too would recommend keeping your element names the same and only changing the actual language of the written text. Otherwise your doing a lot of extra work for something nobody using your site is actually going to see.